# Specifying a theme in android manifest prevents automatic screen orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

If I do not specify a theme in my android manifest, the screen automatically rotates when device changes orientation. But as soon as I specify a theme in the application or activity tags, automatic screen rotation ceases to happen. This is regardless of whether I specify a standard android theme or a custom one.

Automatic rotation happens with this:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    ...
</application>
```

But not with this:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
    ...
</application>
```

This is on an Identity Tab and the API target is Android 2.1-update1

Comment: Funny. Works fine here when I tried.

Comment: @source.rar: What device and API target are you using? I am using and Identity Tab and API target is android 2.1-update1

Comment: Checked with the emulator target 1.6. Is this specific to the tablet?

Comment: yep, confirmed works in emulator. thanks. will do some more snooping on this - maybe try out on other devices. likely to be a device-specific issue then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the device / implementation. Tried it on a phone from a different vendor and it works.

Thanks @source.rar for the emulator clue. Since I had a device I hadn't bothered to check on the emulator.